# FFMpeg HLS Video Transcoding Generating Partial Playlist

Tags: video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, transcoding

I'm trying to convert a basic mp4 video into an HLS video using ffmpeg (running on OSX) using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -codec:a aac -strict experimental -start_number 1 out.m3u8
```

It does manage to generate all of the `.ts` segment files, but the resulting `.m3u8` playlist file only lists the final four segment files, cutting out any earlier segments. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the  [ffmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1), the playlist defaults to 5 entries and a segment duration of 2 seconds. This probably explains why you are only seeing a limited number of entries in the playlist. Try setting the length of the playlist (`-hls_list_size`) to 0, which will include all the segments. Apple [recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-MEDIASTREAMSEGMENTATION-USE_10_SECOND_TARGET_DURATIONS) a segment duration of 10 seconds. You can set the segment duration with the `-hls_time` option.

For reference, you can also use the [segment](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) muxer. Here's the command I usually use when [segmenting video with ffmpeg](http://hlsbook.net/segmenting-video-with-ffmpeg/):

```
ffmpeg -y \
 -i input.mov \
 -codec copy \
 -bsf h264_mp4toannexb \
 -map 0 \
 -f segment \
 -segment_time 10 \
 -segment_format mpegts \
 -segment_list "/Library/WebServer/Documents/vod/prog_index.m3u8" \
 -segment_list_type m3u8 \
 "/Library/WebServer/Documents/vod/fileSequence%d.ts"
```

In this instance, the input video contains H.264 video and AAC audio so it doesn't need to be transcoded.

Comment: The `hls_list_size` flag solved it perfectly, thanks. I saw that in the docs and overlooked it because I assumed that they'd just use the (to me) sensible default that would include all of the files. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -start_number 1 -hls_list_size 0 out.m3u8
```